# How to pass list of boolean values from model class and initialize it in stateful widget?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, boolean

When i am passing a list of boolean statically it works perfectly fulfilling my logic, but when i pass the list of boolean from model it is not working fine.

```
  List<bool> colorSelected = [
    true,
    true,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false
  ];
```

This is my model class:

```
class ProductDetail extends Equatable {
  List<bool> repeatOn;

  ProductDetail(
      {
        this.repeatOn
      });

  @override
  List<ProductDetail> get props => productDetailList;
}

final List<ProductDetail> productDetailList = [
  ProductDetail(
      repeatOn: [false, false, true, false, true, false, true],
];


  ProductDetail pd=ProductDetail();
```

In my statefulwidget, i am initializing it like this in init method

```
 colorSelected=pd.props[0].repeatOn;
```

But when i am running this it always return me false for all values of colorSelected. But it should return me 3 true boolean values in the list. Can you please guide me where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you don't need to get props in class

you should create your class like this

```
class ProductDetail {
  List<bool> repeatOn;

  ProductDetail({
      this.repeatOn
  });
}
```

and when you make an object from your class you should pass it `ProductDetail` not a list of `ProductDetail`

```
final ProductDetail productDetailList = 
  ProductDetail(
      repeatOn: [false, false, true, false, true, false, true],
    );
```

after all for accessing your list items

```
colorSelected = productDetailList.repeatOn[0];
```